# Is there any benefit to using html beginform with no parameters as opposed to a plain <form> tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there really any difference between

```
<form method="post" action="/Controller/Action"></form>
```

and

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller")) {}
```

when none of the other more complex parameters are used?

I know this question sounds really basic, but I am cautious to just use plain HMTL such as the former example.

Comment: same.  If you're going to do former it may be better to still let Razor render the url: <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Controller", "Action")"></form>

Comment: When I read the title I took it wrong as I wrote my answer, Html.BeginForm with no parameters means it doesn't include action and controller parameters so I understood the question to be difference between BeginForm() and BeginForm("Action", "Controller").. the actual question was slightly different tho. Anyway, I think we covered all the bases tho and I upvoted dbaseman as he truly explained the difference between the two form tags in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It renders the same, and it is the same.  The one possible advantage to the Razor syntax is that it's compiled, so there's no chance you'll be able to run your code without neglecting to add the </form> tag.  I guess, arguably, it's also slightly more readable, especially if the rest of the file is heavy on Razor syntax.

Comment: If it's worth mentioning; inside a razor code block, you can't open a `form` tag without closing it anyway. You'll get a runtime error. So inside a code block, is there absolutely no extra benefit of using the `Html.BeginForm` helper?